# Showing multiple records on the same row in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview, webforms

May I know how to show multiple records on the same row in Gridview?

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of these enumerable data bound controls is to show one record/row/object per item template. If you want to show multiple records/rows/objects you will need an intermediate step to aggregate the individual record/row/object together.

then you could bind to the gridview. however, i would recommend the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) so you can customize the layout however you like.

Comment: Thanks! But I need to add some buttons in the view and change the database accordingly after clicking them. Now in Gridview, I used  buttonfield to do so. Can I do the same thing in ListView?